# Is there any default css file for zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I tried to find the default css file for zend framework project .

Is there any default css file for zend framework actually?

How can i change the css style of a form text input textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no default css. Zend Framework is more on the library side than your Cake so you cannot expect it to deliver half an application for you. But what you can expect is rock solid, highly secure and very flexible components!

Comment: What do you mean by rock solid? Can i create eCommerce application with Zend Framework ?  What's the latest version of Zend Framework? And Did you mean it's rock stable ?

Comment: Why are you asking me about the latest version of Zend Framework??

Comment: Of course you can build an eCommerce application with Zend Framework (Google Magento).

Answer (score 0):

There is no default css file for ZF as much as i know.You could insert css files easily in your view`s index.phtml or layout file using this command:

```
 $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('./css/mycustomcss.css');
```

and when you appended and or prepended all your css files,you may write following code to actually display it:

```
 echo $this->headLink();
```

For styling Zend forms [check this useful blog post](http://robertbasic.com/blog/styling-the-default-zend_form-layout/) and zend framework documentation regarding [decorators.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.decorators.html)

You can also set additional HTML attributes for the  tag by using the setAttrib() or setAttribs() methods. For instance, if you wish to set the id, set the "id" attribute:
     $form->setAttrib('id', 'login');
or

```
$form->setAttrib('class', 'zend-form')
->addAttribs(array(
     'id'       => 'registration',
     'onSubmit' => 'validate(this)',
));
```

another example which is for Zend_Form_Element_Text:

```
$primaryEmail = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('primaryemail');
$primaryEmail->setAttrib('size', 35)->setAttrib('class', 'another_row');
```